# Display Responsive Overlay when hovering over image

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to be able to display an overlay over an image when it is hovered over.

I want the overlay and the image to be responsive and adapt to the screen:

```
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
```

This is working on the actual image, but when ive tired to add i the overlay i cant seen to get the overlay responsive by using percentages.

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2NV3/

So when you drag the screen larger and smaller I want the image and the overlay to expand with the screen using %.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```css
.grid li {
    padding:0
}
#mainwrapper .box .slide-caption {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    left: 100%;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2NV3/4/)

Comment: Thanks, but its not what i mean. If you look at this http://jsfiddle.net/w2NV3/2/ if you resize the panels you can see the image expand to the screen. I need the overlay on hover to do the same, as the site is responsive, so when its on a smaller screen it still works

Comment: Thanks mate, one slight thing the height of the image seems to be cut off and not expanding correctly - on #mainwrapper .box, i cant seem to get the width and height auto expanding using %?

Comment: Also if you shrink the panels the caption overlay is bigger than the image?

Comment: Im after something like this: http://thevectorlab.net/flatlab/gallery.html if you resize the screen you can see it adapt, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out famcybox:http://webdesignandsuch.com/fancybox-image-overlay-packaged-for-download/

I think this is what you are looking for